# Is it possible to work with one drive files with Azure Ad Graph API?

Tags: azure, azure-ad-graph-api

I'm working with Azure AD Graph Api (not the MS Graph API), because it's a better choice for some reason in my application. I didn't find any post or text about it, that I'd like to access the onedrive files and work with them with this API. Is it possible or I have to use the MS Graph Api for that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Azure AD Graph API only exposes the Azure AD data, not OneDrive.

You will need to use Microsoft Graph API or the [OneDrive API](https://dev.onedrive.com/).

You should be able to use multiple APIs in your application.

Comment: Thank you so much!

Comment: Am I think correctly, that the access token what I use for Azure AD Graph Api isn't working for Microsoft Graph Api? So am I need to sign-in/auth twice if I'd like to use both in one application?

Comment: User does not need to sign in twice. You will need to acquire a token for both APIs separately though. With web apps using authorization code flow, you can use the same code to get both tokens. With a native command-line app for example, it might need to pop-up the browser window again for the other token, but it will automatically sign in since user has an active session.